# how to display looping process status via javascript worker

Tags: javascript, loops, output, progress, web-worker

I'm dealing with Javascript workers and I need to display the percentage value during a long looping process.
The worker obj sends a message to display the current progress value only at exact tens: 10, 20, 30 % ... so to not mess up the messages queue.
As I try to update such percentage into a table cell `<td>`, I notice that only 3 max 4 values come out.
But this does not happen (i.e., all percentage values are displayed) if `document.title` is used as output or if I dump'em in the `console.log`

Any ideas ?
Am I missing something in my code ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem for many times.
The loop will run to end and after the loop as finished the out put will came.

For loop interaction, you can use a delay like this.

```
function myLoop(){

                    setTimeout(function(){
                        log.consol("Loop run " + i);
                        i++;
                        if(i < 1000)
                        {
                            myLoop();
                        }
                    }, 3000); // delay
 }
```

Comment: I can't: there would be much stuff to send. Basically, it's the problem I wrote above. I just need someone's workaround about that, which I presume to be a usual issue coming out with web workers.

Comment: Ok what is The next step?

Comment: I don't know now ... waiting for someone else to give a more coincise response to my question ? :-)